# in matlab exit the entire loop and more

Tags: matlab

I am using this function to get a column vector in which every element is supposed to be 1, 
but after n gets large, sometimes some element is not 1, this is due to the method constraint, I want to find out how large is n and return the value. the problem are: 1.it seems that 1 is stored as 1.0000, don't know how to convert it, and how to compare(location in comments) 2. don't know how to exit a loop completely. thank you.

```
function x = findn(n)

for m = 1:n
    [a,b]=Hilbert(m);
    m1 = GaussNaive(a,b);
    m2 = size(m1,1);
    % m1 is a n*1 matrix (a column vector) which every element is supposed 
    % to be 1, but when n gets large, some element is not 1.
    for i = 1:m2
        if (m1(i) ~= 1)
        % this compare isn't really working, since 1 is stored as 1.0000 for whatever
        % for whatever reason and they are not equal or not not equal.
        % I doubt whether it really compared.
        x = m;
        break;
        % it just exit the inner for loop, not entirely
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Matlab all numeric variables are, by default, double precision floating-point numbers.  (Actually strings and logicals can look like f-p numbers too but forget that for the moment.)  So, unless you take steps that your code doesn't show, you are working with f-p numbers. The sort of steps you can take include declaring your variables to have specific types, such as `int32` or `uint16`, and taking care over the arithmetic operations you perform on them. Matlab's attraction to double-precision floating-point is very strong and it's easy to operate on `int`s (for example) and end up with floating-point numbers again. Start reading about those types in the documentation.

The reasons for avoiding (in-)equality tests on f-p numbers are explained on an almost daily basis here on SO, I won't repeat them, have a look around.  The straightforward way to modify your code would be to replace the test with

```
if (m1(i) ~= 1)
```

with

```
if ((abs(m1(i)-1)>tol)
```

where `tol` is some small number such that any number larger than `1+tol` (or smaller than `1-tol`) is to be considered not equal to `1` for your purposes.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, Matlab lacks a statement to `break` from an inner loop to outside a containing loop.  However, in this case, you can probably replace the `break` with a `return` which will return control to the function which called your function, or to the command-line if you invoked it from there.